# How to store stream sorted maps into files?

Tags: java

I have sorted a map using a stream like this:

```
Stream<Map.Entry<Character, Float>> sorted =
                hm.entrySet().stream()
                   .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
```

I want to store all the values(sorted) into a text file. How can I do that?

Comment: And your problem is?...

Comment: How can I store the sorted map into the file?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. I just need a way to save the sorted map to a file.

Comment: "I have a map that I want to write to a file. This is how I did it..." That's cool and all, but what is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorted stream doesn't actually do anything without a terminal operation. Collect it to a `LinkedHashMap` and then iterate over that:

```
Map<Character, Float> sorted = hm.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new);
```